# Spring Security : Issue with Authorities

Tags: java, spring-security

I've implemented Spring Security using a custom `AuthenticationProvider`. I've set the authorities by providing a `List` of `GrantedAuthority`. When I retrieve this `List` later from the `SecurityContextHolder`, it seems to be different than what I've originally set.

Here's some sample code to reproduce the issue:

**Authentication Code**

```
/*
3 Granted Authorites are set
1. ABCD
2. EFGH, IJKL
3. WXYZ
*/
List<GrantedAuthority> userAuthorities =
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(new String[]{"ABCD","EFGH, IJKL","WXYZ"});
```

**Retrieval Code**

```
List<GrantedAuthority> retrievedUserAuthorities = (List<GrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
/*
 Retrieved Granted Authorities contains 4!!!
 1. ABCD
 2. EFGH
 3. IJKL
 4. WXYZ
 */
```

How to resolve this issue?

Here's the minimal version of my custom `AuthenticationProvider`:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        List<GrantedAuthority> userAuthorities =
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(new String[]{"ABCD","EFGH, IJKL","WXYZ"});
        User user =
                new User("programmer@stackoverflow.com", "", true,
                        true, true, true, userAuthorities);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, userAuthorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Spring version is **4.2.5.RELEASE** and Spring Security version used is **4.0.4.RELEASE**.

Comment: Could you please add your CustomAuthenticationProvider ? Actually public static List<GrantedAuthority> createAuthorityList(String... roles) accepts infinite parameters and converts it to List. Does "EFGH, IJKL" is a single role ?

Comment: Will add it. Yes, it's a single authority.

Comment: @kaliatech - In my example, the String array has just three Strings. May be the comma in second String makes it appear to have four Strings?

Comment: Yes, I missed that detail.Sorry.  I do not see any reason for you to be getting four authorities in the `getAuthorities` call. I'd suggest setting a debugging break point on the `getAuthorities` call and then stepping through to see if that provides any more info.

Comment: @kaliatech- I debugged the code already. While setting, the list size is three but while retrieving it's four. Need to find how and where the List is modified.